# Show alt image on error. Laravel - vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to see if there is an image for an item and if not I want to show a default image. This is where I'm trying to do it, in a vuetify data-table. I removed everything else except the image part, as everything else is working as expected

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="courses">

    <template v-slot:item.image="{ item }">
        <img width="120" height="80" :src="item.image"
            @error="this.src='https://www.logistec.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/placeholder.png'"/>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

This doesn't give me any errors but doesn't show the `@error` image, right now the `item.image` is null, so it should show the other image, I even have it downloaded in `public/image/placeholder.png` in case that makes a difference.

Right now it just shows this, an empty box.

[image]

How can I fix this to show the alternate image when the `item.image` is null?

Comment: Is this answer your question? https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5404#issuecomment-413486473

Comment: @cbaconnier I checked that out but I don't know if that would work for me since I'm getting the src dynamically with each table row

Comment: What about the answer using the `event.target.src` ?

Comment: @cbaconnier I ended up just doing an if else to check if the image was null or not and setting the src depending on that, I did test the suggestion you sent but it didn't work like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Try it. I am using Laravel 8 Version.

```
<img :src="`uploadimage/${post.post_photo}`" :alt="`${post.post_title}`">
```